# Find a way to catch error when mapping business entity to appointment in Scheduler Devexpress control

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

In our project we are using Devexpress sheduler conrol. Our entity is mapped correctly and we are able to see appointments on view. Everything works fine except that now we need to add validation logic inside setter of business entity. And now at runtime when end of appointment is changed if it violates business rules - application crashes because there is no exception handling. I can't find a way to catch this error when mapping is performed.

Can somebody suggest how/where to catch this error when mapping from/to appointment?

Code of Property that has validation:

```
    public DateTime StartDateTime
    {
        get { return _startDateTime; }
        set
        {
            if (_startDateTime != value)
            {
                OnSetStart(value);
                _startDatetime = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("StartDatetime");
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnSetSart(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        if(PisiblePeriodStart <= dateTime && dateTime <= PosiblePeriodEnd)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error")
        }
    }
```

It just a sample code of how validation can look like. Posible Period is interval of valid values.

Comment: How does the end of the appointment change?Using the EditForm?
Do you allow appointment drag-drop?

Comment: It happens when I try to drag/drop or resize appointment

Comment: Can you post a sample of your validation logic?

Comment: I have extended question with sample of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to duplicate you validation logic you can try something like this

```
    bool IsStartValid;
    public DateTime StartDate
    {
        get { return startDate; }
        set
        {
            if (value > MaxValidDate)
            {
                IsStartValid = false;
                throw new Exception("Error");//***
            }
            else
                IsStartValid = true;
           startDate=value;
        }
    }
```

You can handle the AppointmentDrop event of the SchedulerControl and check the IsStartValid property

```
private void schedulerControl_AppointmentDrop(object sender, AppointmentDragEventArgs e)
{
        YourClass temp = e.EditedAppointment.GetRow(schedulerStorage1) as YourClass;
        if(temp.IsStartValid==false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Start");
            e.Handled = true;
           e.Allow = false;
        }
       // if (e.EditedAppointment.End < DateTime.Now)
       // {
       //     MessageBox.Show("You can't move appointments to the past");
       //     e.Handled = true;
       //    e.Allow = false;
       // }
 }
```

The same for the AppointmentResizing event

***IS THIS EXCEPTION UNHANDLED???

Comment: Yes, that's how I'm handling it for now. But I has some validation logic inside setter and I would like to use logic from there, when Appointment end is mapped. I thought it had some event like OnMappingComplete or OnDataBindingcomplete where I can handle error.

Comment: @Ash You will have to use some event but i don't think you will find something like OnBindingComplete...
I cannot think someting better that this,

Comment: Yes, exception is unhandled so application will crush. It looks like your answer is only option for now.

Comment: That is not a good idea.Remove the throw Exception and use the IsStartValid Property to check if your object is in valid state